# How to use state in anonymous method using react in component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, anonymous-function

I have react component like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Sidebar, Segment, Button, Menu, Image, Icon, Header } from 'semantic-ui-react'

export default class Footer extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            visible: false
        }
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
        this.handleClick();
    }


    handleClick() {

        this.props.socket.on('connect', function () {
            console.log("PRINT this.state.visible");
            console.log('Connected');
        });

        this.props.socket.on('disconnect', function () {
            console.log('Disconnected');
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className='create-task-section'>
                "HELLO"
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

I am using websocket io. In method `this.props.socket.on` I want print

`this.state = {
      visible: false
}`

But when I print this variable, I am getting undifined error. How can I read/change/update `this.state` values in anonymous method like`this.props.socket.on`?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You must not `bind` the `handleClick` method but the anonymous function.

Comment: I assume you meant `console.log("PRINT", this.state.visible)` not `console.log("PRINT this.state.visible")`?

Answer (score 2):

bind 'this'.

```
this.props.socket.on('connect', function () {
            console.log("PRINT this.state.visible");
            console.log('Connected');
        }.bind(this));
```

to change state variable use 'this.setState({visible: false})' never mutate state with this.state.visible as that wont work. Also event handling should be done in componentDidMount method, not on handleClick as it will not work till user clicks.

Comment: why do you bind `this` to function instead of using es6 arrow function?

Comment: @MaximKuzmin there are many ways to bind 'this'. Arrow functions are also good. Initializing a bound function in the constructor is also good. using es7 "::" for bound is also there. using react instance method is also good.